# diffrence between design pattern, programming pattern,design model

Tags: design-patterns

while learning diffret ways to code in a pl i noticed there is mulitple way to called design pattern or even some refering as programming patterns but i also noticed there is sth called a model that i think it is the way files are managed in a project

are they correct or is there anything that i am missing. like another design thing or else ...
i am currently studying C# and i found design patterns like command design pattern or observer design pattern and i C# docs found things like TAP TPL ... which i dont know are all same thing or is there any diffrence between tap and command design pattern and ...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.